# SQL CASE in Where Clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I have a two optional parameters empName, empLoc. Both of these parameters can be null, empty or have some value. If both has values, i will have to get all the values, if empName has value then i only need to get value where empName is equal to passed parameter @empName, and same with @empLoc. I know i can write separate sql's in same stored procedure but i want to do it using CASE clause, since it is going to save most of the repeated code. However i am having problem while setting up query. And i know it's the CASE clause.
Here is what my query looks like:

```
SELECT 
     EmpID,
     EmpDept
FROM Employee
WHERE TimeStamp = @timeStamp
 **AND (CASE
        WHEN DATALENGTH(@empName) > 0 THEN EmployeeName LIKE '%' +@empName+'%'
      ELSE
         EmployeeLocation LIKE '%' +@empLoc+'%'
      END)**
```

NOTE: im already doing null check for these parameters. Also this query will only run if either @empName or @empLoc has some value.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: You didn't say what your problem is...

Comment: Why are you even using `LIKE`? Shouldn't this information be stored somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually you must put the DATALENGTH(@empName) <= 0 on the second part of the OR because the CASE implies an exclusive OR. So the correct one would be:

```
SELECT 
     EmpID,
     EmpDept
FROM Employee
WHERE TimeStamp = @timeStamp
AND 
(
    (DATALENGTH(@empName) > 0 AND EmployeeName LIKE '%' +@empName+'%')
      OR
    (DATALENGTH(@empName) <= 0 AND EmployeeLocation LIKE '%' +@empLoc+'%')
)
```

Comment: I like this pattern which is commonly referred to as "Catch All Queries". Be sure to add an OPTION (RECOMPILE) to the end of the statement so that the query optimizer can do it's job better and possibly avoid (very) bad performing queries. More info: http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` is an expression that returns a value:

```
where TimeStamp = @timeStamp and
  CASE WHEN DATALENGTH(@empName) > 0 AND EmployeeName LIKE '%' +@empName+'%' THEN 1
    WHEN EmployeeLocation LIKE '%' +@empLoc+'%' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
    END = 1
```

Comment: This will result in a scan. It's Better to use the pattern suggested by Tiago.

Comment: @buckley - Both this approach and Tiago's will use an index on TimeStamp, if any.  Any `LIKE` pattern that starts with a percent sign will require a scan.  What am I missing?

Comment: A like pattern that starts with a % can still benefit from a non clustered index on the column because it will result in a scan of fewer data (I tested this just now).
With the scan above I meant a plain scan (table scan in case of a heap or clustered index scan) which the optimizer is forced to do if you give it a CASE in the where.
Tiago converted the where clause to a SARG which gives the optimizer  more options (even though the optimizer could decide not to use an index *at that point in time*).

Comment: One should always strive to create queries with sargs as you probably know. This allows the dba to create indices when certain queries get too slow without altering code = chance of introducing bugs. Don't you agree to avoid the CASE or do you see advantages to it?

Comment: @buckley - I understand the SARGability issue.  In my defense, I was trying to address the OP's question re `CASE` syntax without going to far afield.  Your remark about using an index with `LIKE` still has me puzzled.  I've found information about how the optimizer uses selectivity statistics to determine how to process a `LIKE`, but nothing that indicates a "like pattern that starts with a % can still benefit from a non clustered index ...".  Could you point me to a resource that explains it?  SO keeps teaching me how little I know.  That should be their Sales Mark.

Comment: SO does the same for me :) I tested my assumption before commenting. This is where the like sarg, even though it starts with a %, uses a nci scan http://screencast.com/t/guhWxsz2JVE

Comment: I generated lots of data in that table and there is a tipping point where the optimizer sees that the ammount of logical reads for table/ci scan is more than using the nci. I used redgates data generator to come up quickly with a few million rows but I think the tipping point doesn't require so many. http://screencast.com/t/nAjHRSqMq0 I made the table wide - lots of columns - so that the cost of a table/ci scan would be greater. Let me know if it makes sense now

Comment: @buckley - It looks like it is saving reads by scanning the NCI rather than the table.  If so, making the rows longer would also encourage the use of an NCI scan.  Or, in the OP's case, creating NCIs on TimeStamp with EmployeeName as an included column and TimeStamp with EmployeeLocation included.  Thanks for the follow up!

Comment: Your thinking is sound. The number of (logical) reads is one of most important number the optimizer takes into account (+cpu/memory). Since a nci is almost always smaller than a table/ci scan it will become a good candidate. But any necessary bookmarks lookups are a perf killer since it requires random IO. If few rows are returned the optimizer can still consider it.

Comment: In case of the column the like is searching on it will possibly take into account the density info contained in the index to (wild) guess the cardinality. If the query is covering as you say it's a *very* good candidate since the bookmark lookup is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEN function if you want to trim space

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(' ') --Result is 1
SELECT LEN(' ') -- Result is 0
```

Answer (score -1):

you don't need to `case when` statement for this problem

```
SELECT 
     EmpID,
     EmpDept
FROM Employee
WHERE TimeStamp = @timeStamp
 AND
    ( ( DATALENGTH(@empName) > 0 AND EmployeeName LIKE '%' +@empName+'%')
      OR
      ( DATALENGTH(@empName) = 0 AND  EmployeeLocation LIKE '%' +@empLoc+'%'))
```

Comment: DATALENGTH(@empName) = 0 should be DATALENGTH(@empName) <= 0

Comment: DATALENGTH will never return negative. so "=" is enough. Can you write a text have negative length?

Comment: That's an assumption you I presume since It isn't in the documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx Note that I agree that it is unlikely but what if this function returns negative numbers to signal exceptions? It seems better to keep them logically equivalent.